# Why are "look" and "school" pronounced differently?

Tags: pronunciation

I can't figure out a rule that says whether 'oo' makes one sound or the other. Same number of syllables: one closed, but the sound is different.

Comment: You are operating under the delusion that English spelling primarily represents pronunciation. It actually represents word origin primarily, and pronunciation only secondarily.

Comment: One word for you: [ghoti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghoti)

Comment: @mplungjan *ghoti* was coined as a parody. And the proposed pronunciation is not correct  because 'ti' isn't prounounced 'sh' at the end of the syllable ever; only when followed by an 'on', or such. Also, 'gh' isn't pronounced anything other than 'g' when it's not at the end of the syllable. But, yeah, what you're trying to imply is true.

Comment: ti as in nation - ghoti is not pronounced fish, g/h/o/ti can be pronounced fish

Comment: And "Raymond Luxury Yacht" is apparently pronounced "Throat Warbler Mangrove".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth made me laugh out loud!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no 100% reliable spelling or pronunciation rules in English but there are exceptions and patterns which can be recognized and memorized.

My accent is British and the following words are how they are most often pronounced in the UK. American English may or may not share the same pronunciation.

The letter combination, oo, usually has two sounds: /uː/ and /ʊ/. 
**School**, **boot**, and **choose** are pronounced as /skuːl/, /buːt/ and /ʧuːz/

**Good**, **took**, **book**, and **look** are pronounced: /gʊd/, /tʊk/, /bʊk/ and /lʊk/ but **foot** which logic dictates should imitate the long *u* vowel in *boot* is instead pronounced as /fʊt/. However, the short vowel sound is kept in **football** which is pronounced as /ˈfʊtbɔːl/.

Other words which are spelt with *oo* include **blood** and **flood** which are pronounced respectively /blʌd/ and /flʌd/ but **food** which could have the short vowel as in *good*, or share the same vowel sound as in *flood* is pronounced as /fuːd/!

In other words, you need to memorize the pronunciation for each English word and when in doubt, check with a dictionary (or ask a native speaker to help you out).

Comment: You forgot the sound `/o:/` in words like *door*, *floor*, *blood*... Though some of these are pronounced `/u:/` in some places.

Comment: Then there's _coordinate_ . . .

Comment: Coordinate used to be hyphenated: co-ordinate, thus was not originally an oo word.

Comment: +1 Thorough answer. I've never pronounced *foot* and *football* differently, nor been aware of others doing so. But (altho' I haven't yet had a chance to even attempt to understand the pronunciation symbols) I note you actually use the same symbols for the relevant part of both words (unless the initial 'apostrophe' / 'tick' mark in the second is relevant?). This reminds me, in part, of the now old-fashioned notion of the upper/middle classes having a 'posh' way of pronouncing certain words.

Comment: Now there's _coordinate_ . . .

Comment: @EdwinAshworth coordinate was two words that were hyphenated then lost even the hyphen. But ares till pronounced as if they were two words

Comment: @mgb No  – 'co' was never a word. It is a bound morpheme. And the word coordinate is a single word with an unusual pronunciation, due as you say to its inner structure.

Comment: @TrevorD: I think you misunderstood what Mari-Lou was saying about foot and football: she used the same symbol because they are pronounced the same (in all varieties of English AFAIK). I think the _however_ misled you.

Comment: In Manchester _book_ and _look_ are /buk/ and /luk/ rather than /bʊk/ and /lʊk/. On the other hand, I've discovered some people pronounce _tooth_ /tʊθ/ where I have always said /tuθ/. I'm not sure whether that's regional or individual variation. I think _roof_ also has some variation.

Comment: @Gorpik Blood is pronounced differently to door and floor. And I'm unfamiliar with the [phonetic symbol](http://calleteach.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/sounds-of-english-introduction/) you posted, I've never seen it before. I don't claim to be an expert, but I have found the [IPA chart](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/pronunciation.html) to be a useful tool for learners of English.

Comment: *Door* is usually pronounced as **/dɔː/**; *floor* is **/flɔː/** whereas *blood* is **/blʌd/** likewise *flood* is **/flʌd/**

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: Thank you. It was important that someone corrected that.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You are right. I thought of the difference for *blood* (or *flood*) later, but until now I haven't been near a computer. As for the phonetic symbols, you are right again, I should have bothered to copy the right ones instead of just using my keyboard.

Comment: @Gorpik 'Bother to' is normally limited to negative ('I shouldn't have bothered to ring him') and interrogative ('Did you bother to go and see her?') constructions. ' I should have taken the trouble to copy the right ones instead of . . .'